# How to references correctly Java Projects into Web Dynamic Project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an eclipse Java Project `MyProject` with the package `com.myproj`, that uses some libraries: `xstream` and `jfreechart`.
I have also an eclipse Web Dynamic Project `WebProject` with the package `com.webproj`, that depends on some classes in `com.myproj` and that uses the library `jfreechart`.

The `MyProject` works perfectly.

In the Java Build Path of the `WebProject` there is the `MyProject`, and `MyProject` is also in the Deployment Assembly.

But every time I run the `WebProject` it can't start because of an `ClassNotFoundException` related to `xstream`, after this:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamDriver  at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)

Answer (score 1):

**Right click your web project -> Properties ->  Java build path -> Libraries -> Add Jars.**

Now add all the XStream related dependencies, which are present in your Java project, in your web project as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you run WebProject, make sure that is also build the dependent projects (MyProject). My guess is that it only cleans the projects.